# Having Multiple versions of Jquery

Tags: jquery, multiple-versions

Ok the site I just started uses jquery 1.4.min to run a dynamic page changer which I got off a site. And it also uses 1.6.2 to run a photo slider which I also got off another site. I want both to work but it wont let me. Some ppl told me to only use one version of jquery (most recent) but that didn't work and everyone else says use:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>  
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict(true);  
</script>
```

and replace all $ with $jq. First I don't know if I replace all $ from the min.js file as well or just the function. Either way I tried both and it still didn't work. This is a link to my site SO FAR. http://envycosmetics.zxq.net/Website/webpages/index.html

In my site the Dynamic Page loader is working properly but not the slider

Comment: The best I will suggest is to use latest version of jquery and debug why the current plugins are not working.updating all plugins to the latest versions may solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You really should just use the latest version and include it only one time at the top of the page.  You need to modify the dynamic page changer to run under the current version of jQuery.  It's sloppy to have two versions going at a time.

Comment: Ya i rly wouldn't mind using the lastest version but I have no clue how your supposed to modify the scripts to work then

Comment: It looks like you have it working, unless someone goes to a different page and returns back to the index :/  I think what is happening with that is the slider script needs to be reinstantiated each time the index page is called.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use an Iframe to load the photo slider, which uses a different version of jQuery. Build the photo slider in a different HTML page and load that in the IFRAME